# Applet is not initialized in this simple guessing play

Tags: java

I have to write an applet plays the game "guess the number". It should select a random integer between 1 and 1000. It must have a JTextField and a button that if the player's guess is incorrect, it should clear the JTextField so the user can enter the next guess. The program should count the guesses and with each good guess each should eliminate half of the numbers.

This is what I have done so far but there are some problems:

1) When I run the program it shows "applet is not initialized"
Why? Where is the problem?

2) How to call the button to clear the JTextField after each time the player plays?

3) Is my algorithm to eliminating half of the numbers true or it should be changed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
package guess.number;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuessNumber extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
  JLabel promptLabel;
  JTextField inputField;
  JButton button;
  int guessNum;   //is given from the user.
  int randomNum;
  int min =0;
  int max =1000;

public void init() {

 Container container = getContentPane();
  container.setLayout( new FlowLayout() )
  promptLabel = new JLabel( "guess a number between 1 and 1000: " );
   inputField = new JTextField( 10 );
 String text = inputField.getText();  //this line and next make applet uniniialized.i guess.
    int guessNum=Integer.parseInt(text);
     button= new JButton("Enter");
     inputField.addActionListener( this );
     button.addActionListener(this);
    container.add( promptLabel );
    container.add( inputField );
    container.add(button);

 }
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource()==button)
        randInt(min,max);
   }

public  void randInt(int min,int max){

Random rand = new Random();
 int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
comp(randomNum);

}

public  void comp(int randomNum){
    int count=0;

while(guessNum!=randomNum )
{
    if(guessNum<randomNum){
        count++;
        showStatus("too low!try again");
        if(guessNum < randomNum/2)
            randomNum=randomNum/2;  //eliminates half of the numbers.
          }
    else 
            if(guessNum>randomNum){
            count++;
            showStatus("too high!try again");
        }

}

     if(guessNum==randomNum){
          if (count<10)
               showStatus("correct!you guessed the number, nice play!");
           else 
            if(count>10)
                  showStatus("correct!you guessed the number but try better for next times!");
              else 
                if(count==10)
                   showStatus("correct!you guessed the number ,good job!");

            }



}


}
```

Comment: Why aren't you setting the text in the actionPerformed? Why are you trying to eliminate the numbers, what does that do for your program?

Comment: does it make difference to set them in the actionPerformed?eliminating is asked in the question:"with each “good guess” the player should be able to eliminate half of the numbers."

Comment: It's likely that "int guessNum=Integer.parseInt(text);" is causing a parse exceptin, which is preventing the applet from been intilaised

Comment: thats true but i have to cast the type to compare with randomNumber.then what should i have to do?